# Using Search Api Solr indexed search?

Tags: 8, search

I Installed [search api solr module][1] and solr-5.5.2 server.
When I tried to add server in drupal backend(/admin/config/search/search-api/add-server) , I'm getting warning message as shown in attached image and I'm not able save the settings.Can anybody help me in this?
http://192.168.88.89:8983/solr/#/drupal8  is my solr server which is running
[image]

Though i added the configuration, why i'm not able to save.Is there any other settings? I have moved solr-conf/5.x files to server/solr/drupal8/conf.

Answer (score 1):

For the solr core name, try using just "drupal8" instead of "/index/drupal8"

Here are the settings I'm using locally:

[image]

[image]